Finding a bound for optimal solution of a quadratic optimization problem
Suppose that $A\succeq 0,$ $0\le y$ and $\|y\|\le \|x_\rho\|, \mu \in \mathbb R^n,$ and $e$ be the vector of ones. My goal is to show $\{x_\rho\}$ is bounded when large enough $\rho$ goes to $+\infty$, where
\begin{equation}x_\rho= \frac{1}{2}(A+\rho I)^{-1}\left(\mu +2 \rho y+
\frac{1-0.5e^T(A+\rho I)^{-1}(\mu +2\rho y)}{0.5e^T(A+\rho I)^{-1}e}e
\right).\end{equation}
Notice that $x_\rho$ is the solution of the following problem:
\begin{equation}
\min_{x\in \mathbb R^n} x^TAx-\mu^Tx+\rho\|x-y\|^2 \quad \mbox{s.t.} \quad e^Tx=1,
\end{equation}
which is related to the mean-variance portfolio optimization problem. I am trying to give an ADMM algorithm for solving this problem and that is why I need to prove the boundedness of $\{x_\rho\}$.
My current efforts are as follows:
In virtue of $A\succeq 0$ and $\rho \ge 1,$ we see that
$$
\|(A+\rho I)^{-1}\|=
{\lambda_{\max}((A+\rho I)^{-1}})=
{1}/{{\lambda_{\min}(A+\rho I)}}={1}/{({\lambda_{\min}(A)+\rho)}}\le 1/{\rho},
$$
and
$$
{n}/{(\lambda_{\max}(A)+\rho)}
=
{\|e\|^2}/{\lambda_{\max}(A+\rho I)}
=
\|e\|^2\lambda_{\min}((A+\rho I)^{-1})\le {e^T(A+\rho I)^{-1}e}.
$$
Thus, since ($\|e\|=\sqrt{n}\ge 1$), we have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\left\|\frac{1-0.5e^T(A+\rho I)^{-1}(  \tau \mu +2\rho y)}{0.5e^T(A+\rho I)^{-1}e}e
\right\|
& \le 
\frac{1+0.5\|e\|\lambda_{\max}((A+\rho I)^{-1})(\tau \|\mu\|+2\rho \|y\|)}{
0.5{n}/({\lambda_{\max}(A)+\rho})
}\|e\|
\\
& \le
\frac{\|e\|(\lambda_{\max}(A)+\rho)}{0.5n}+
{(\lambda_{\max}(A)+\rho)}\|e\|
\frac{\|e\|(\tau \|\mu\|+2\rho \|y\|)}{
{n(\lambda_{\min}(A)+\rho)}
}
\\
& \le
(\lambda_{\max}(A)+\rho)+
{(\lambda_{\max}(A)+\rho)}\|e\|
\frac{\|e\|(\tau \|\mu\|+2\rho \|y\|)}{
{n(\lambda_{\min}(A)+\rho)}
}
\\
& \le
{(\lambda_{\max}(A)+\rho)}
+
{(\lambda_{\max}(A)+\rho)}
\frac{(\tau \|\mu\|+2\rho \|y\|)}{
{\rho}
}
\\
& \le
{(\lambda_{\max}(A)+\rho)}
+
{(\lambda_{\max}(A)+\rho)}
\frac{(\tau \|\mu\|\rho+2\rho \|y\|)}{
{\rho}
}
\\
& \le 
(\lambda_{\max}(A)+\rho)
(1+\tau \|\mu\|+2\|y\|).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Hence,  the above and the equation for $x_\rho$ together with $\|y\|=\|H_k(x^+)\|\le \|x^+\|\le \|x\|$ lead to\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\|x\| 
&\le
\frac{1}{2} 
\|(A+\rho I)^{-1}\|
(\tau \|\mu\|+2\rho\|y\|
+(\lambda_{\max}(A)+\rho)
(1+\tau \|\mu\|+2\|y\|)) 
\\
& \le
\frac{1}{2\rho}(
\tau\|\mu\| + 2\rho \|y\|+(\lambda_{\max}(A)+\rho)(1+\tau \|\mu\|+2\|y\|)
)
\\
& \le
\frac{1}{2\rho}(
\tau\|\mu\| + 2\rho \|y\|+(\lambda_{\max}(A)+\rho)(1+\tau \|\mu\|+2\|y\|))
\\
& \le
\frac{1}{2\rho}(
\tau \|\mu\| +(\lambda_{\max}(A)+\rho)
(1+\tau \|\mu\|)+2(\lambda_{\max}(A)+2\rho)\|y\|)
\\
& \le 
\frac{1}{2\rho}(
\tau \|\mu\| +(\lambda_{\max}(A)+\rho)
(1+\tau \|\mu\|)+2(\lambda_{\max}(A)+2\rho)\|x\|)
\\
& \le 
\frac{1}{2}(
\tau \|\mu\| +(\lambda_{\max}(A)+1)
(1+\tau \|\mu\|))+\frac{1}{\rho}(\lambda_{\max}(A)+2\rho)\|x\|
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Unfortunately, the coefficient for $\|x\|$ on the right-hand side is not less than 1, so things do not go through!
I am okay with putting more assumptions on the problem parameters to be able to find a bound for this sequence.
UPDATE:
Thank you all for all the nice and correct answers to the current (above) version of my question. However, I thought I clarified this point in the notes, I forgot to state it in the question formulation. The correct formulation of the question must be as @River Li stated in the last note:
Let $\{\rho_k\}$ be a positive monotone sequence going to infinity. Let $\{x_k\}$ and $\{y_k\}$ be two sequences such that $y_k \ge 0; \, \forall k$, and $\|x_k\|\ge \|y_k\|; \, \forall k$. Further, each $x_k$ is the unique minimizer of the following optimization problem:
\begin{equation}
\min_{x\in \mathbb R^n} \quad x^TAx-\mu^Tx+\rho_k\|x-y_k\|_2^2 \quad \mbox{s.t.} \quad e^Tx=1.
\end{equation}
What I really need to prove is that $\{x_k\}$ and $\{y_k\}$ are bounded or suffieiceintly $\{x_k\}$ is so.

What's the relation between $x_{\rho}$ and $y$ (you write $|y|\le |x_\rho|$ and $|y|=|H_k(x^+)|\le |x^+|\le |x|$ etc.)?

@RiverLi Thanks for your comment. In fact, in my ADMM method, the original portfolio has other constraints, specifically, $x\ge 0$ and $|x|_0\le k$, and the role of $y$ is taking care of them. $y$ indeed turns out to be the sparsifying operator $H$ of $x^+=\max(x,0)$ and that is why I have those inequalities, that is, $y$ takes $k$ largest components of $x^+$.

So, some constraints are hidden in the beginning description of the problem? In other words, it is not to prove that $x_{\rho}$ is bounded by some constant $C(A, \mu, y)$ (i.e. dependent of given $A, \mu, y$, independent of $\rho$)?

The original problem of interest is the mean-variance portfolio problem that has a cardinality constraint as well. This problem has three constraints: $e^Tx=1, x\ge0$, and $|x|0\le k$. My ADMM algorithm splits them with a new variable called $y$ that takes care the last two constraints. As $\rho$ goes to infinity, $x$ and $y$ converge to each other. To prove the existence of an accumulation point for my method, I need the boundedness of the sequence $x\rho$ independent of $\rho$. Hope this clarifies things.

OK. Perhaps (not sure), we can try to prove the result without these information, i.e., given $A, \mu$,
for variables $x_\rho$ and $y$
satisfying $0 \le y$, $|y| \le |x_{\rho}|$, and the equation, prove that
$x_{\rho}$ is bounded by $C(A, \mu)$ (independent of $\rho$).

Exactly, this is how I tried to formulate the question and that is enough for my purposes but because I was not successful in proving it, I am now thinking that maybe we should simultaneously prove the boundedness of the sequences ${x_\rho}$ and ${y_\rho}$ where $y_\rho=H_k(x^+\rho)$. Roughly speaking, a pair of $(x\rho, y_\rho)$ must satisfy the original problem constraints, which are bounded! This shows the existence of an accumulation point for my method.

I think that a special case of your problem is described as follows: Let $\rho_k = k = 1, 2, \cdots$. Let ${x_k}_1^\infty$ and ${y_k}1^\infty$ be two sequence of $n\times 1$ vectors such that $y_k \ge 0, \forall k$,
and $|x_k| \ge |y_k|, \forall k$,
and $x_k, \forall k$ is the minimizer of the following optimization problem
$$\min{x\in \mathbb R^n} x^TAx-\mu^Tx+ k|x-y_k|^2 \quad \mbox{s.t.} \quad e^Tx=1.$$
You hope that ${x_k}$ is bounded (or ${x_k}$ and ${y_k}$ are both bounded).

@RiverLi This is exactly right. By the way, I am still trying to analyze your answer. Thank you very much for that.

For your update, perhaps you may use the sequence ${\rho_k}$ which converges to infinity, rather than $k$ (because $k$ is used to denote $1, 2, \cdots$ in $x_k, y_k$).

By the way, it seems $y \ge 0$ is necessary. For example, when $A = 0$ and $\mu = 0$ and $e^\top y_k = 1, \forall k$. Then the minimizer is always $x = y_k$. Without $y\ge 0$, how about $y_k = [-k, k, 1, 0, \cdots, 0]^\top, \forall k$?

Further, any example to describe that $|x| \ge |y|$ is necessary?

Updated! Yes, $y\ge 0$ is necessary as you pointed out with I guess you meant $y_k=[-k,k+1,0,\dots,0]$.

Note that
$$
(A+\rho I)^{-1}=\rho^{-1}\big(\rho^{-1}A+I)^{-1}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{\rho\rightarrow\infty}\big(\rho^{-1}A+I)^{-1}=I\ .
$$
Using these two observations, we have
\begin{align}
x_\rho&=\\
\frac{1}{2}(A+\rho I)^{-1}&\left(\mu +2 \rho y+
\frac{1-0.5e^T(A+\rho I)^{-1}(\mu +2\rho y)}{0.5e^T(A+\rho I)^{-1}e}e
\right)\\
=\frac{1}{2}\big(\rho^{-1}A+I\big)^{-1}&\left( \rho^{-1}\mu +2y+
\frac{1-0.5e^T\big(\rho^{-1}A+I\big)^{-1}\big(\rho^{-1}\mu +2y\big)}{0.5e^T\big(\rho^{-1}A+I\big)^{-1}e}e
\right)\\
\rightarrow y+&\left(\frac{1-e^Ty}{n}\right)e
\end{align}
as $\ \rho\rightarrow\infty\ .$  Thus, since $\ x_\rho\ $ converges as $\ \rho\rightarrow\infty\ ,$ it must be bounded.  As one might expect, its limit is in fact the value of $\ x\ $ which minimises $\ \|x-y\|^2\ $ subject to the constraint $\ e^Tx=1\ .$
Proof for updated problem
The above observations can be used to prove that $\ \big\{x_k\big\}\ $ is bounded by contradiction. Suppose otherwise.  Then there's a subsequence $\ \big\{x_{k_j}\big\}\ $ of $\ \big\{x_k\big\}\ $ such that $\ \big\|x_{k_j}\big\|\rightarrow\infty\ $ as $\ j\rightarrow\infty\ ,$  and since $\ \left\|\frac{x_{k_j}}{\big\|x_{k_j}\big\|}\right\|=1\ ,$$\ \left\|\frac{y_{k_j}}{\big\|x_{k_j}\big\|}\right\|\le1\ ,$ the sequence $\ \left\{\left(\frac{x_{k_j}}{\big\|x_{k_j}\big\|},\frac{y_{k_j}}{\big\|x_{k_j}\big\|}\right)\right\}\ $ lies inside a closed ball (of radius $\ \sqrt{2}\ $) of $\ \mathbb{R}^{2n}\ ,$ a compact set. Therefore there's a subsequence $\ \left\{\left(\frac{x_{l_j}}{\big\|x_{l_j}\big\|},\frac{y_{l_j}}{\big\|x_{l_j}\big\|}\right)\right\}\ $ of
$\ \left\{\left(\frac{x_{k_j}}{\big\|x_{k_j}\big\|},\frac{y_{k_j}}{\big\|x_{k_j}\big\|}\right)\right\}\ $ that converges:
\begin{align}
\lim_{j\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x_{l_j}}{\big\|x_{l_j}\big\|}&=\hat{x}\ \ \text{ and}\\
\lim_{j\rightarrow\infty}\frac{y_{l_j}}{\big\|x_{l_j}\big\|}&=\hat{y}\ ,
\end{align}
say, where $\ 1=\big\|\hat{x}\big\|\ge\big\|\hat{y}\big\|\ ,$ and $\ \hat{y}\ge0\ .$  By the same calculation used above to obtain expressions for $\ x_\rho\ ,$ we have
\begin{align}
x_{l_j}=\frac{1}{2}\big(\rho_{l_j}^{-1}A+I\big)^{-1}&\left(\rho_{l_j}^{-1}\mu +2y_{l_j}+
\frac{1-0.5e^T\big(\rho_{l_j}^{-1}A+I\big)^{-1}\big(\rho_{l_j}^{-1}\mu +2y_{l_j}\big)}{0.5e^T\big(\rho_{l_j}^{-1}A+I\big)^{-1}e}e
\right)\ .
\end{align}
Dividing this identity through by $\ \big\|x_{l_j}\big\|\ $ and taking limits as $\ j\rightarrow\infty\ $gives
$$
\hat{x}=\hat{y}-\frac{e^T\hat{y}}{n}e\ ,
$$
or
\begin{align}
1&=\big\|\hat{x}\big\|^2\\
&=\big\|\hat{y}\|^2-\frac{(e^T\hat{y})^2}{n}\\
&\le1-\frac{(e^T\hat{y})^2}{n}\ ,
\end{align}
which is impossible, because if $\ \hat{y}\ne0\ $ then $\ e^T\hat{y}>0\ $ and therefore $\ 1-\frac{(e^T\hat{y})^2}{n}<1\ ,$ and if $\ \hat{y}=0\ $ it gives $\ 1=0\ .$ Therefore $\ x_k\ $ must be bounded.

Thank you very much for your neat answer! Please kindly see the updated question (last part)!

Some thoughts.
Conjecture 1. Let $A$ be a given $n\times n$ symmetric positive semi-definite matrix.
Let $\mu$ be a given $n\times 1$ vector.
Let $e$ be the $n\times 1$ vector of ones.
Let $\rho > 0$. Let $x$ and $y$ be two $n\times 1$ vectors such that $y \ge 0$ and $\|x\| \ge \|y\|$ and
$$x = B(\mu + 2\rho y) + \frac{1}{e^\top B e} Be - \frac{e^\top B (\mu + 2\rho y)}{e^\top B e} B e$$
where $B := \frac12(A + \rho I)^{-1}$.
Then $e^\top y$ is bounded for sufficiently large $\rho$.
Discussion.
We have
$$x = B(\mu + 2\rho y) + \frac{1}{e^\top B e} Be - \frac{1}{e^\top B e} B ee^\top B (\mu + 2\rho y) $$
and
$$x = 2\rho\left(B - \frac{1}{e^\top B e} B ee^\top B\right)y
+ \left(B - \frac{1}{e^\top B e} B ee^\top B\right)\mu + \frac{1}{e^\top B e} Be$$
and
$$x = Py + z$$
where
$$P := 2\rho\left(B - \frac{1}{e^\top B e} B ee^\top B\right), \quad z := \left(B - \frac{1}{e^\top B e} B ee^\top B\right)\mu + \frac{1}{e^\top B e} Be.$$
We have
$$\|y\|^2 \le \|x\|^2 = y^\top P^2 y + \|z\|^2 + 2z^\top P y $$
and
$$\frac{1}{n}(e^\top y - 1)^2
+ y^\top \left(I - P^2 - \frac{1}{n}ee^\top\right)y
\le \frac{1}{n} + \|z\|^2 + 2\left(z^\top P - \frac{1}{n}e^\top\right)y $$
and (using $Pe = 0$ to obtain $(P + \frac{1}{n}ee^\top)^2 = P^2 + \frac{1}{n}ee^\top$)
$$\frac{1}{n}(e^\top y - 1)^2
+ y^\top \left(I - \left(P + \frac{1}{n}ee^\top\right)^2\right)y
\le \frac{1}{n} + \|z\|^2 + 2\left(z^\top P - \frac{1}{n}e^\top\right)y.$$
We have
$$\lim_{\rho\to \infty} P = I - \frac{1}{n}ee^\top, \quad \lim_{\rho\to \infty} z = \frac{1}{n}e,
\quad \lim_{\rho \to \infty} z^\top P = 0.$$
When $\rho$ is sufficiently large,
we have $z^\top P - \frac{1}{n}e^\top < 0$.
If we can prove that
$$I \succeq P + \frac{1}{n}ee^\top,$$
then we have, for sufficiently large $\rho$,
$$\frac{1}{n}(e^\top y - 1)^2 \le \frac{1}{n} + \|z\|^2.$$

Thank you very much for your interesting conjecture. I updated the question after our discussion in the notes.

let $x_\rho$ be the solution to
$$\min_{x\in \mathbb R^n} f(x)+\rho\|x-y\|^2$$
for some function $f$ which is bounded below by $b$ (and assume that a unique solution exists).
Let $\varepsilon>0$ then for every $x$ outside of the ball $B(y,\varepsilon)$ we have
$$f(x) +\rho\|x-y\|^2 \ge b+\rho \varepsilon^2$$
Therefore if $f(y)<b+\rho \varepsilon^2$ nothing outside of $B(y,\varepsilon)$ can be the minimum so, rearranging, for
$$\rho>\frac{f(y)-b}{\varepsilon^2}$$
$x_\rho$ is always in $B(y,\varepsilon)$. Hence, for any $\varepsilon$ we can find $\rho^*$ large enough that $x_\rho \in B(y,\varepsilon)$   for any $\rho > \rho^*$. So $x_\rho$ limits to $y$ as $\rho \to \infty$, hence is bounded for large $\rho$.
Your problem is almost of this form, but with an additional restraint that $x$ be in some hyperplane $P$.
By the Pythagorean theorem
$$\rho\|x-y\|^2=\rho\|x-z\|^2+\rho\|y-z\|^2$$
Where $z$ is the point in $P$ closest to $y$, but $\rho\|y-z\|^2$ is just a constant, so solving your problem:
$$\min_{x\in P} f(x)+\rho\|x-y\|^2$$
is the same as solving
$$\min_{x\in P} f(x)+\rho\|x-z\|^2$$
But for any hyperplane $P$, there is a distance-preserving affine map $P \to \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. By using this map, we can make $x$ range over $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ instead of $P$, so we can apply our result and find that
$$\lim_{\rho \to \infty}x_\rho=z$$
hence $x_\rho$ is bounded for large $\rho$.

Addendum:
Technically your $f$ doesn't have to be bounded below by a constant, if $A$ isn't positive semidefinite, but it has to be bounded below by $b+c\|x-y\|$, so we can use the same approach because we can still always find a $\rho$ big enough that
$$f(y)<b+c\|x-y\| +\rho\|x-y\|^2$$
for all $x$ with $\|x-y\|>\varepsilon$

Thank you very much for your intuitive answer! Please kindly see the updated question (last part)!

I've now added a proof for the updated problem

@lonzaleggiera Thanks very much. I will go through your proof as soon as possible.
